# Load XML file to dataframe in PySpark using DBR 7.3.x+

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, apache-spark-xml

I'm trying to load an XML file in to dataframe using PySpark in databricks notebook.

```
df = spark.read.format("xml").options(
    rowTag="product" , mode="PERMISSIVE", columnNameOfCorruptRecord="error_record"
).load(filePath)
```

On doing so, I get following error:

```
Could not initialize class com.databricks.spark.xml.util.PermissiveMode$
```

Databricks runtime version : 7.3 LTS Spark version : 3.0.1 Scala version : 2.12

The same code block runs perfectly fine in DBR 6.4 Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade version of `spark_xml` library to a version compiled for Scala 2.12, because the version that works for DBR 6.4 isn't compatible with new Scala version. So, instead of `spark-xml_2.11` you need to use `spark-xml_2.12`.

P.S. I just checked with DBR 7.3 LTS & `com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.11.0` - works just fine.